# Increment the length of a copied motion path using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to create a row of duplicated objects in PowerPoint, each with a motion path that is slightly shorter than the next, like this:

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huHrW.png)

I know that you cannot add a path animation from scratch in VBA, so I used VBA to copy and paste an object and its motion path, then edit the motion path.

This is my VBA code:
        Sub CopyPastePosition()

```
    ' Copy the shape in slide 2 which has a custom motion path aleady
    ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(3).Copy

    Dim x As Integer
    ' For loop - create 5 duplicates
    For x = 1 To 5
    ' Each duplicate is nudged to the left by x*100
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste
      .Name = "Smiley"
      .Left = x * 100
      .Top = 1
    End With

   ' This is where I am unsure - I want the motion path to be longer by x amount each time

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence(x).Behaviors(1).MotionEffect.Path = "M 0 0 L 0 x*0.7"

Next x
End Sub
```

However, the output is like this:
[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NK8Y.png)

Comment: I know  nothing about powerpoint vba, but if i were forced to guess, i would try... `"M 0 0 L 0 " & (x * 0.7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I realise that I am trying to insert a variable into a string. yes the correct way of doing this is `"M 0 0 L 0 " & (x * 0.7)`

Thank you @braX

Answer (score 2):

Path property for motion path which represents a VML string. The VML string is a collection of coordinates for a Line or Bezier curve (for 
powerpoint purposes). **The values are fractions of the slide dimensions.**

You can generate an incrementing VML path with this function.

```
Function GetPath(MaxSegments As Integer, Increment As Single)
Dim path As String
Dim i As Integer

path = "M 0 0 "

For i = 1 To MaxSegments
   path = path & "L 0 " & CStr(Increment * i) & " "
Next

path = path & " E"

GetPath = path
End Function
```

Since you are doing copy/paste of a shape with motion path already on it, I would also make this change to ensure we reference the correct motion path upon paste:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine
     .MainSequence(.MainSequence.Count).Behaviors(1).MotionEffect.path = GetPath(x, 0.7)
End With
```